# Autocomplete Search With Link

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, autocomplete

So I'm Creating A School Management System And On The View Students Page I'm Wanting A Autocomplete Search System That Returns A Link Which Will Link To Another Page

But It Needs To Look Through The Students Table To Get The id For The Page As Its viewrecord.php?id= then the students id, and also the name of the student for autocomplete system, how can this be done with mysqli?

I previously tried, this is it without sql selection, it didn't work with links:

```
<input type="text" name="srch" id="srch" list="datalist1">
<datalist id="datalist1">
  <option value="Canada">
  <option value="China">
  <option value="Mexico">
  <option value="United Kingdom">
  <option value="United States of America">
  <option value="Uruguay">
</datalist>
```

something like that ^^^

```
The students table is below
id bigint(20), Auto Incrememnt And Primary
first_name varchar(255)
last_name varchar(255)
room varchar(255)
dob varchar(255)
And Finally 
email varchar(255)
```

Comment: So, Construct a link in your result ;)

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen yes, it produces a link, no search button, so its making a link with all the the id from the data base

so say jeff's id is 6, and michaels is 4
if i search for jeff, the link will goto viewrecord.php?id=6

Comment: Yeah you can do it.. Do you want me to help in it ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen It Would Be Helpful To Know How It Can Be Done :), So Yes Please

Comment: Thank You @SulthanAllaudeen I've Been Looking For This And I Haven't Been Able To Figure It Out Yet

Comment: Still Waiting @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: Have just posted answer and you can get the working code directly here ;) http://wikisend.com/download/640654/autocomplete-search.zip

Comment: Here's my Demo for you ,, You can search your or my name here http://sysaxiom.com/test/levi/autocomplete-search/ and it should sugget you :)

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Yes It Is, Thank You Very Much I Needed This, Nice!

Comment: You're welcome, If my answer helped you. You can accept it by clicking on the tick button near my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a workaround like this

**Step 1 :**

Get the input in the textbox and have a jquery which triggers in keyup function

```
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{
//your ajax call here
}
```

**Step 2.**

Inside the function have an ajax call to another file which queries for your input

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "search.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
//your action
}
});
```

**Step 3 :**

In the success, you can replace the result inside the div near your search

```
$("#result").html(html).show();
```

**Step 4 :**

Inside the `search.php` you can get the input and query for the table and for result, and construct a hyper link which suits your need.

i.e., `user.php?id=xyz`

So that you can navigate to that page easily

Which would have the code something like

```
<a href="user.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>"><span class="name"><?php echo $username; ?></span>
</a>
```

[Here is the source code](http://wikisend.com/download/640654/autocomplete-search.zip) and [here is the demo](http://sysaxiom.com/test/levi/autocomplete-search/) i have created a demo which suits your needs just for you ;)